# Mapping nested components in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a 'User' Entity that contains an 'Address' Value Object.  I have this mapping ok using FNH's Component concept.  However, the Address VO also contains a Country which is another value object.  I had assumed that this should be just nested as another component, but this doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone tell me how I should solve this?

Code for mapping is below...

Thanks!

```
public UserMapping()
        {
            Table("Users");
            Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");
            Map(c => c.UserName).Not.Nullable().Length(64);
            Map(c => c.Email).Not.Nullable().Length(128);
            Map(c => c.Password).Not.Nullable().Length(256);
            Map(c => c.Roles).Length(64);
            Map(c => c.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(64);
            Map(c => c.LastName).Not.Nullable().Length(64);
            Map(c => c.BirthDate).Not.Nullable();
            //Address
            Component(x => x.Address, m =>
            {
                m.Map(x => x.AddressLine1).Not.Nullable();
                m.Map(x => x.AddressLine2);
                m.Map(x => x.City).Not.Nullable();
                m.Map(x => x.Region);
                m.Map(x => x.PostalCode).Not.Nullable();
                //*****Country Here********
                // country has Name and Code

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, Jimmy Bogard from the FNH mailing list showed me - it's quite straightforward.  I don't know what I was doing before!  Anyway, for anyone else who's interested:

```
Component(c => c.Address, m =>
{
    m.Component(cp => cp.Country, m2 =>
    {
        m2.Map(x => x.Name); //etc
    }
```

Comment: Amazing. I did not realize you could nest them like this. I have been working on doing this for a week.

Comment: What if I have IdCountry in Address for country instead of Name and Code (provided that IdCountry is the primary key of Country)?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a map for `Country` and use `m.References(x => x.Country)`.

Comment: But then wouldn't that be treating country as an Entity rather than a value object?  Maybe there's no downside with doing that though.

Comment: There is a downside. Entities have their own "life" (what affects all selecting and updating queries) and we do not want here to have an `Address` which live on its own.